# Does the back-end database matters in terms of speed, while reading through spark?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, apache-spark

Currently I am using *Spark* with *Cassandra* as a data storage (I have some NoSQL requirements). *Spark* has its own in-memory processing framework and can be connected to various databases like *Cassandra*, *MongoDB*, *Redshift*.

So while reading from these databases through *Spark*, does the read performance (or write performance) of the database matter? I was looking to change the data storage for faster reads.

Comment: Impact of the database performance will vary on a case by case basis but it definitely cannot be ignored. In a typical scenario you cannot bypass database engine so IO performance is a clearly a limiting factor. Of course it works both ways. You most likely want to avoid executing Spark queries on non-replicated production database.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for your input. That explains my doubt. By the way, have you tested different databases with spark to check the read/write performance? or gone through suck material. I want to use a database that will be fast for querying/loading/updating through Spark.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, of course it does. 
Basically what spark does, it reads from the datastore using all executors, and the faster your database can provide the data the faster Spark will get access to that data.

If you want faster reads, setup a datastore that is scalable for read in a way that reads can be made in parallel from different machines, so you're not being bound to limits of 1 machine.